# Être aveugle à / devant quelque chose

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions

Y a-t-il a une différence entre les usages de *à* et *devant* dans ce cas ?

> Les adultes s'attachent à ce qu'ils dénomment « rationnel », ils se préoccupent pour les biens matériels et ils sont aveugles **devant** / **à** ce qui se cache au-delà de ce qu'ils peuvent voir.

Ou **être aveugle à** est une expression figée ?

Comment: Normalement les gens sont aveugles *devant* ce qui se cache. Est-ce que le *a* fait partie de la phrase originale ?

Comment: Non. C'est 'devant', mais ma prof m'a dit qu'il avait quelque chose mal dans cette phrase et j'ai pensé que c'était *être aveugle à*.

Comment: La phrase est une forme de tautologie logique : s'ils ne peuvent pas voir, les gens sont aveugles, ils sont donc aveugles *devant* (mot adapté à la situation : *devant* une limite qui masque la vue) ce qui est caché, ce qui est logique... ce qui renvoie aux limites de la vue.

Comment: Donc, la phrase est correct avec *devant*?

Comment: Tout à fait, c'est le fait  qu'elle manifeste une évidence, sans apporter de réponse ou une amorce de solution qui peut interloquer.

Comment: Le problème n'est-il pas "ils se préoccupent **pour** [...]" ?

Comment: Est-ce qu'il  doit être *par*?

Comment: « Ils sont (seulement) préoccupés par les biens matériels » (ou « ils s'intéressent seulement aux biens matériels »). « Ils se préoccupent des biens matériels » serait un usage correct mais n'a pas le bon sens (cela signifierait qu'ils font ce qu'il y a a faire, pas qu'ils ne s'occupent pas d'autre chose).

Comment: Est-ce que "ils se préoccupent par les biens matériels" ne va pas bien? @Gilles

Comment: Non. On s'occupe ou on se préoccupe *de* quelque chose. On *est préoccupé par* quelque chose, au passif.

Comment: Peux - tu faire une réponse pour te choisir?

Answer (score 3):

«Être aveugle à la misère humaine» est une abstraction, un état, la misère humaine étant un concept dans ce cas.

«Être aveugle devant la misère humaine» est le refus, le choix de ne pas voir ce qui est devant soi.

Answer (score 1):

*[L'expression originale](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/aveugle) <sup>(2-a.5)</sup>* est figée : « (Sourd et) *aveugle **à*** » :

> ... en l'imaginant sourd et aveugle *à* tout, ...

Sinon on peut être aveugle : ...*devant* une situation, ...*pour* ne pas reconnaître un fait, ...*des* couleurs, ...

---

**EDIT**

*[L'usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aveugle%20%C3%A0%2Caveugle%20devant%2Caveugle%20pour&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caveugle%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caveugle%20devant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caveugle%20pour%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Caveugle%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Caveugle%20devant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caveugle%20pour%3B%2Cc0) "aveugle à"* est majoritaire, mais la requête ramène des *à* qui ne sont pas liés à aveugle.

*[Précédé de](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%AAtre%20aveugle%20%C3%A0%2C%C3%AAtre%20aveugle%20devant%2C%C3%AAtre%20aveugle%20pour&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%AAtre%20aveugle%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%AAtre%20aveugle%20devant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%AAtre%20aveugle%20pour%3B%2Cc0)* être, *"aveugle à"* est moins courant que *être aveugle pour*.

Answer (score 0):

Techniquement, *« être aveugle à »* et *« être aveugle devant »* devraient avoir la même signification. Cependant, l'expression utilisée en français est *« être aveugle à »*.
L'autre sonne honnêtement bizarre ...

De plus, j'aurais dit *« ils se préoccupent des biens »* plutôt que *« ils se préoccupent pour les biens »*.

Answer (score 0):

**Sourd** à est fréquemment utilisé = deaf to

**Aveugle** à: je n'ai jamais vu cette construction. Elle me semble inexacte  de nos jours (sauf en conjonction avec sourd). Je ne l'ai pas trouvée dans les dictionnaires.

**Devant** ce que l'on veut: peut être employé dans n'importe quelle construction: c'est un complément circonstanciel.

Avec aveugle, je dirais aussi *aveugle* face à cette situation.

Comment: * Combien, souvent, elle reste aveugle à ce que cache la vérité !* Marcel Proust, La Prisonnière.

Comment: @jlliagre merci de l'exemple, j'ai donc mis à jour ma réponse.

Comment: *Être aveugle à* est au contraire une expression dont la fréquence est en augmentation. ex.: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reste+aveugle+%C3%A0&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creste%20aveugle%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @jlliagre je ne sais pas comment fonctionne ce comptage, mais je ne trouve rien sur internet et google sur "aveugle à" - ce ne serait pas le comptage de "à l'aveugle", qui lui donne beaucoup de résultats ?

Comment: Non, l'ordre des mots est pris en compte. *Être aveugle à* apparaît dans de nombreux  ouvrages récents. Il suffit de suivre les liens présents sous le graphique. C'est aussi une expression facilement trouvée par les moteurs de recherche. Elle n'a rien d'inexact ou d'exceptionnel.